# Is adjustResize deprecated or only WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE?

Tags: android, android-windowmanager, android-input-method, android-layoutparams

After trying to mess around with soft input mode, the only thing that work for my requirement is setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` of the activity in manifest and `activity?.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)` in specific fragment to allow me have a dynamic input mode between fragments.

Upon trying multiple setup I noticed that `adjustResize` programmatic approach `WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE` is deprecated but I don't see any deprecation warning when it is being used in the manifest nor in the Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#wsoft). This is also the default behavior I am getting when `windowSoftInputMode` is not specified. What is it that we are actually deprecating here? Is the two approach the same or not?